# Django - Two Users Accessing The Same Data

Tags: python, django, multithreading

Let's say that I have a `Django` web application with two users. My web application has a global variable that exist on the server (a `Pandas Dataframe` created from data from an external `SQL` database).

Let's say that a user makes an `update` request to that `Dataframe` and now that `Dataframe` is being updated. As the `Dataframe` is being updated, the other user makes a `get` request for that Dataframe. Is there a way to 'lock' that `Dataframe` until user 1 is finished with it and then finish the request made by user 2?

EDIT:

So the order of events should be:

User 1 makes an update request, Dataframe is locked, User 2 makes a get request, Dataframe is finished updating, Dataframe is unlocked, User 2 gets his/her request.

Lines of code would be appreciated!

Comment: "My web application has a global variable ..." - stop right there. No.

Comment: Global variables are not always evil, but you have to be aware of how they work in a context of a multi-threaded application where you don't control the threads

Comment: @MadWombat 

Understood, how should I approach this? If both users are attempting to gather the same data from the external database, it makes sense to cache it right?

Answer (score 2):

Ehm... Django is not a server. It has a single-threaded development server in it, but it should not be used for anything beyond development and maybe not even for that. Django applications are deployed using WSGI. WSGI server running your app is likely to start several separate worker threads and will be killing and restarting these threads according to the rules in its configuration.

This means, that you cannot rely on multiple requests hitting the same process. Django app lifecycle is between getting a request and returning a response. Anything that is not explicitly made persistent between those two events should be considered gone.

So, when one of your users updates a global variable, this variable only exists in the one process this user randomly accessed. The second user might or might not hit the same process and therefore might or might not get the same copy of the variable. More than that, the process will sooner or later be killed by the WSGI server and all the updates will be gone.

What I am getting at is that you might want to rethink your architecture before you bother with the atomic update problems.

Comment: Sorry, it's been a long day. I am deploying my application through WSGI. 

If two users try to access the same data from an external database, it makes sense to catch it right?

Comment: Can you and do you want to write the data updates back into the SQL database you are getting it from?

Comment: I can and I would want to write the data back.

Answer (score 1):

Don't share in memory objects if you're going to mutate them. Concurrency is super hard to do right and premature optimization is evil. Give each user their own view of the data and only share data via the database (using transactions to make your updates atomic). Keep and increment counters in your database every time you make an update, make transactions fail if those number have changed since the data was read (as somebody else has mutated it).

Also, don't make important architectural decisions when tired! :)

Comment: Thanks I think I will take this approach!